# Karma doesn't execute templateUrl or controllerProvider functions on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an unexpected issue with karma-jasmine on any browser. I'll try to provide each required resource for my tests:

```
//Dependencies and karma.conf

"jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
"karma": "^0.13.15",
"karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.1.5",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
"phantomjs": "^2.1.7",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",

 browsers: ["PhantomJS", "Chrome_without_security"],
 customLaunchers: {
   Chrome_without_security: {
     base: "Chrome",
     flags: ["--disable-web-security"]
   }
 },
```

With above configuration, I run my tests with our custom state provider, which is able to create dynamic templateUrl and controllerProvider fields for our states. We also use ui-router.

When I run the application everything works fine and my state is created as follows

```
"url": "/sms-otp",
"pubViews": {
    "appView@": {
        "auth": {
            "templateUrl": "/modules/core/authentication/sms-otp/sms-otp.html",
            "controller": "smsOtpController as smsOtp"
        },
        "guest": {
            "templateUrl": "/modules/core/authentication/sms-otp/sms-otp.html",
            "controller": "smsOtpController as smsOtp"
        }
    },
    "menuView@": {
        "auth": {},
        "guest": {}
    }
},
"bodyClassList": "sms-otp-page-body",
"views": {
    "appView@": {
       templateUrl: function() { ... },
       controllerProvider: function() { ... }
    },
    "menuView@": {
       templateUrl: undefined,
       controllerProvider: undefined
    }
}
```

TemplateUrl and controllerProvider are executed on browser but not on karma-jasmine. What might be the problem, do you have any ideas?